# Does an aggregation of two lambda/2 dipole antennas z-axis oriented radiate towards the mentioned axis?

Tags: antenna, radiation, dipole

I'm asked whether by grouping two dipole antennas pointing towards the z-axis, they'll radiate in that direction. I'm aware each dipole alone doesn't do that thus refraction lobes in the z-axis direction won't show up, but my main question is whether the grouping somehow make lobes appear in the z-axis because aggregation factor.[image]

Comment: Hm, could you define the "Z axis"? I cant imagine the direction the antennas are pointing to. Or better, could you draw it/ show it in 3D?

Comment: @ Christianidis Vasilis. The two dipoles are parallel to the z-axis and are placed next to each other along the y-axis. Let's imagine that the center of the first dipole is located at (0,0,0), and the center of the second dipole is at (0, a, 0). Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use some java's programs at http://amanogawa.com/archive/Antenna2/Antenna2-2.html ...

Answer (score 4):

No.  The radiation pattern will still be perpendicular to the Z-axis; perpendicular to the length of the antennas.  The combined pair will radiate in the x-y plane.

Exactly what that pattern looks like depends on 1) the spacing d, 2) the frequency/wavelength of operation and 3) the phase relationship between the inputs (feeds) to the two antennas.